# symfony2 service extends another class

Tags: symfony, php

I had written the class service before I received the new task. I need to expand my service..

I had:

```
namespace Trucking\MainBundle\Service;
use Trucking\MainBundle\classes\Scan;

    class ScanService  {

        public function scan() { 
          // code
        }
    }
```

I've upgraded the service

```
namespace Trucking\MainBundle\Service;
use Trucking\MainBundle\classes\Scan;

class ScanService extends Scan\Process\Process  {

    public function scan(Scan\IScanVirtual $virtual) { 
        $virtual->start($this);
    }
}
```

**Services.yml**

```
scan_storage:
  class : Trucking\MainBundle\Service\ScanService
  arguments: [path,container,movetime,checkpoint]
```

**I have an error :**

> message":"Runtime Notice: Declaration of Trucking\MainBundle\Service
> \ScanService::scan() should be compatible with that of
>  Trucking\MainBundle\classes\Scan\Process\Process::scan() in C:\webserver\symfony\src\Trucking\MainBundle\Service
> \ScanService.php line 11","class":"ErrorException","trace":[{"namespace":"","short_class":"","class":"","type":"","function":"","

**ScanService.php line 11:**

```
ScanService extends Scan\Process\Process
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scan()` in `ScanService` has a different number of argument of `Process` (or a different access level). This is pure PHP and has nothing to do with Symfony.